# Data Representation Question

Tags: computer-science, number-systems, binary, floating-point

A computer stores a number of $16$ bits word using floating-point arrangement. Given that the first bit is reserved for the sign and followed by $6$ bits for the exponent using biased form. The remaining bits are used for the mantissa with a hidden bit.

(a) Show how the computer stores $-37.87510$.

(b) What is the decimal value for $0100\ 1111\ 0111\ 0101_2$?

My Attempt Was :

(a) = $000100101.1110 = 15.D$

(b) = $2^{14} + 2^{11} + 2^{10} + 2^9 + 2^8 + 2^6 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 1 = 20341$

Please help me out, I want to know if I'm doing it correct...

Comment: Your answer to (b) is certainly wrong.  The first six bits, after the sign, are not $2^{14}$ etc; they are the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

1. Convert $-37.8751$ forces the first bit to be set; now convert $37.8751$ to binary and express this as $1.??? \times 2^{???}$ and this is where you will get your mantissa and exponent to store in the arrangement you described.
2. First bit is not set, so the number is positive. Exponent is the next 6, i.e. $100111$. The remaining bits are the mantissa (does it really have 2 as the last digit?), convert each one from binary $1.??? \times 2^{???}$ to decimal and you are done.

Comment: The OP states $6$ bits for the exponent follow the first sign bit.

Comment: @JohnHabert made the edit, thanks for the catch

Comment: You're welcome. I'm as confused as you are about the $2$. Note that it is actually the $17^{\mathrm{th}}$ 'bit' listed. Maybe that is the hidden bit? That still doesn't explain why it is $2$.

Comment: @JohnHabert must be a typo of some sort...

Comment: I think I just figured it out. I think the OP is supposed to read $0100\ 1111\ 0111\ 0101_2$.

Comment: @JohnHabert :-) nothing like imagination and creativity when sorting through weird question formulations :-)